# Do you know Python libs to send / receive files using Bittorent?

Tags: python, bittorrent

I have bigs files to move to a lot of servers. For now we use rsync, but I would like to experiment with bittorent.

I'm studing the code of Deluge, a Python bittorent client but it uses twisted and is utterly complex. Do you know anything hight level?

EDIT: I just read that Facebook does code deployment using Bittorent. Maybe they published their lib for that, but I can't find it. Ever hear of it?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/python-libtorrent/ might be helpful. It is a Python wrapper around the C++ libtorrent library.

Comment: It's been included in the deluge project and is now drawn in 1000 lines of code with no cookbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I definitely recommend [libtorrent-rasterbar](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/). It's a C++ library with Python bindings. The same one that powers Deluge, Transmission, Miro and many other bittorrent clients.

In contrast to the other libtorrent (the one that is part of rTorrent project), this one is under active development and supports all modern protocol extensions, like DHT, metadata transfer and even some proprietary uTorrent extensions like peer exchange (PEX).

The API is very well documented.

As you can see from the following fully functional simple client example, you don't need to understand every bit of the underlying protocol (of course, it helps a lot when you do):

```
#!/bin/python
# Copyright Arvid Norberg 2008. Use, modification and distribution is
# subject to the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
# file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)


import libtorrent as lt
import time
import sys

ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)

info = lt.torrent_info(sys.argv[1])
h = ses.add_torrent({'ti': info, 'save_path': './'})
print 'starting', h.name()

while (not h.is_seed()):
    s = h.status()

    state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', 'downloading', \
        'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating', 'checking fastresume']
    print '\r%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s' % \
        (s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000, \
        s.num_peers, state_str[s.state]),
    sys.stdout.flush()

    time.sleep(1)

print h.name(), 'complete'
```

P.S. Facebook has a dedicated page for their opensource projects at http://developers.facebook.com/opensource/. There's no bittorrent implementation listed.

Comment: Sorry, but the documentation is strange (0_bit, 1_bit are not well explained), there is no specific Python binding documentation (but yeah, would be needed!), and it cannot even be linked with macOS M1, because there is no source available (I get it, it's coming from C++) and it's quite unclear which symbols even are exported... I would not recommend it (but there is probably no other choice, sigh)

Answer (score 2):

The original BitTorrent client is written in Python. Have you checked that out?

Comment: It's very far from hight level. If you don't know the protocol, you are stuck.